# Storage of .apk file in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I have a doubt in android storing the apk files. Some apk files are stored in /system/apps. And some apk files are stored in some other folders . I want to know on what basis the apk files are stored.
Is it on Manifest.xml if so where is it actually located.

Comment: What is your doubt? You really need to do some reading before you flood us with more unanswerable questions ..